# Who was acharya SrirAm Sharma?

Tags: philosophy, guru

He was the founder of gAyatrI parivar. He propagated gayatri worship among the masses.

What is his life story?

What were his main teachings ?

Comment: Search properly before you ask a question. Research effort is also important otherwise, provide a self answer. [How to ask](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shriram_Sharma

Comment: There is a lot more about mission and life. Other than wiki...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

His life story can be found on official website of [All World Gayatri Pariwar](http://www.awgp.org/about_us/patron_founder).

His popular work can be found [here](http://literature.awgp.org/hindi/book,) and [here](http://quotes.awgp.org).

He worked not only for Gayatri worship but also for many other Gods/Goddesses, Yoga, Indian Sanskriti etc. I gave an exam named 'Bhartiya Sanskriti Gyan Pariksha' organised by All World Gayatri Pariwar in my school days and that syllabus covered from Lord Shri Rama to Swami Vivekananda.